# Problems using read.bathy in marmap package

Tags: r

I have a 3 column matrix of longitudes , latitudes, and depths saved as a csv file that I would like to convert to a bathy object. However when using this code I get the following error:

```
myBathy <- read.bathy("marmapbathydata.csv", header=TRUE) 
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
```

`summary(myBathy)` then returns

```
Bathymetric data of class 'bathy', with 651 rows and 691 columns
Latitudinal range: -69.78 to 47.2 (69.78 S to 47.2 N)
Longitudinal range: -179.79 to 8.86 (179.79 W to 8.86 E)
Cell size: 1 minute(s)

Depth statistics:
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.1226  0.0000  2.0000 

First 5 columns and rows of the bathymetric matrix:

          -69.7798 -69.7741 -69.7683 -69.7625 -69.7568
-179.7917        1        1        1        1        1
-179.775         1        1        1        1        1
-179.7583        1        1        1        1        1
-179.7417        1        1        1        1        1
-179.725         1        1        1        1        1
```

My bathymetry data is not rectangular (it has 651 unique longitude values and 691 unique latitude values), but I am using `marmap` version 0.9.1 so this should not be the issue.

How do I resolve this error and get my bathy object?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you get the same error running the `read.bathy` example? Is your csv file correctly formatted?

Comment: I do not get the same error with the example not with a subset of the same csv file.

Comment: I suspect the function cannot handle my full csv because it is a compilation of nonconsecutive latitudes and longitudes and depths. Basically it is made up of multiple spatially separated grids. I could get the function to work as long as I ran each small grid by itself. Is there a way to make the function work for such data without separating the areas?

Comment: From the example and arbitrary removing large sections of the lines, `read.bathy` still works with no warning.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the message your getting is not an error message: the object `myBathy` is created and is recognized as a `bathy` object since `summary(myBathy)` returns the expected output. Are the longitude and latitude ranges of your dataset coherent with the output of `summary(myBathy)`? And what about the depth/altitude values? I noticed that you only have positive values in `myBathy`. Positive values are used for altitudes. If the values refer to depths, they should be negative.

```
myBathy <- -myBathy
```

should do the trick. If your values are indeed altitude values, then, you should not forget to use the `land=TRUE` argument when plotting or you won't see a thing.

If the above doesn't solve your problem, the issue might be due to the "irregular nature" of your bathymetric data. `marmap` needs data that can be arranged in a grid with regularly-spaced longitude and latitude values. Could you post your dataset, or at least a sample of it so I can reproduce the error?

A possible workaround would be to use one of the numerous krigging methods available in R as a first step to extrapolate your data on a regular grid. Here is an example using the `fields` package:

```
library(fields)
myBathy <- read.table("marmapbathydata.csv", header=TRUE) 

## Use krig() to fit your data in e.g. a 300x300 grid. CAREFUL! It can take some time for large datasets!
bat.kr <- Krig(myBathy[,1:2], myBathy[,3])
out.p <- predictSurface(bat.kr, nx=300, ny=300, extrap=FALSE)

## Transform the 'predictSurface' object into a 'bathy' object
bat <- out.p$z
colnames(bat) <- out.p$y
rownames(bat) <- out.p$x
class(bat) <- "bathy"

summary(bat)
plot(bat)
```

Comment: I actually have no positive depth values in my dataset at all. I have no idea where those depth statistics are calculated from. My maximum depth My data set is from multiple oceans and so I believe marmap could not arrange the data into a grid. I would be happy to post a subset of the data, but I am not quite sure how best to post it. How do you suggest I go about it?

Comment: You can put your data on a public repository or in a dropbox and post the link to the file here. If you don't know how to proceed, you can send me the file by email (you can find the email of the maintainer of marmap on CRAN, he will forward it to me). However, other people will only be able to help if you post a link to your data on SO.